# Running MVC and Umbraco 4.7 applications in parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, optimization, umbraco

We are using Umbraco 4.7.1 and it's very slow sometimes, taking more than 10-14 secs to load certain web pages.

Is it possible to create a new MVC web application and use this to display the slow pages instead of Umbraco? The important thing is that it should run on same web server and should replace a specific path currently existing in Umbraco, e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/Product`.

Any suggestions how to improve the performance are also welcome.

Comment: To clarify then, your Umbraco app is slow. And instead of fixing this, you wish to create a separate MVC application that sits at a path that is currently controlled by Umbraco. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct but i want only few pages in MVC like which are slow rest all in umbraco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer. Firstly, yes you can. You can host the MVC application as an application within the site in IIS. You will need to ensure that you override all the web.config settings as these settings will be inherited. You will also need to add an the path of your MVC application to the `umbracoReservedUrls` and/or `umbracoReservedPaths` appSetting in the Umbraco web.config.

However, the second part of the answer is: don't.

Do not create and host a separate MVC application purely because you have performance issues in your Umbraco application. Figure out what is causing the performance issues and fix it. It sounds like you are possibly making too many calls to the database, or the calls that you are making aren't optimized.

My advise would be to run SQL profiler over the site on these pages and check what is happening. You should then review the indexes on the non-umbraco elements of your database, using views where appropriate, and also review whether you are using appropriate caching.